# perform post operation within the server node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am working on express js. A particular endpoint renders the following form

```
<form action="/api/oauth2/authorize" method="post">
  <input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="<%= transactionID %>">
  <div>
  <input type="submit" value="Allow" id="allow">
  <input type="submit" value="Deny" name="cancel" id="deny">
  </div>
</form>
```

And this works perfectly ! But i want to simulate this form submit on the server side, i am doing :

```
                request({
                url : 'http://localhost:3000/api/oauth2/authorize',
                qs:{
                  transaction_id:bod.transactionID                       },
                headers:{
                  'Authorization':auth,
                  'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                method:'POST'
              },function(err,res,bo){
                console.log("Got response with body :"+bo);
              });
```

The problem is that now i am initiating a new http post request and the previous session data is lost. When  i do the POST operation using the form, the session data is still maintained.
How can i simulate the form post such that the session data is maintained, please help !

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I know that if you're using `express-session` for example, the sessions are assigned to the request object by the middleware. If you're wanting to preserve that in this request, you might have to manually add in the request.session data into this data that you're sending. Can you dump the `request` objects data?

Comment: Ya this should work but i don't know if we can dump the request objects data

Comment: I just wanted you to dump the data of `request` so you can see where the session data is stored. Assign the session data in the new request to `request.session`.

Comment: The session data is stored in the request object as req.session, how can i apend the session data with the post request ?